# Cordova on iOS: app has no audio until it is sent to the background

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, audio

Using the Cordova Media plugin, when my app is supposed to play audio, instead it just hangs until I press the home button then all of the audio that was supposed to play begins to play all at the same time, and once I return to the app, audio works as intended.

The issue seems to have appeared after updating our iPad 2 to version 8.4.1.

Is anyone else having this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was fixed by updating Cordova from 4.0.0 to the latest version 5.2.0.